# Doubt proving that there is no natural number between $n$ and $n+1$?

Tags: induction

I'm trying to understand the solution to the following problem I took from Hijab's *"Introduction to Calculus and Analysis":*

> [image]

The solution is:

> [image]
> [image]

We are using the following definition and theorem:

> [image]
>
> [image]

And when he says "from the text" is that he proved earlier in the text that there are no naturals between $1$ and $2$.

**Question:** Why does $n< m-1 < n+1$ contradicts $n\in S$?

Comment: $S$ is literally defined as the set of naturals $n$ such that $n < r < n+1$ is not possible for any natural $r$. So $n < m - 1 < n+1$ contradicts that with $r = m - 1$

Comment: It's recommended to type in the mathematics in latex format rather than use images on this site. I'm surprised such a high reputation user would enter text as images.

Comment: @OXLR - Do you have a reference for the definition that you stated?

Answer (score 1):

If $n<m-1<n+1$, and $m-1\in\mathbf{N}$, then $n$ cannot be a member of the set $S$ for which there are no naturals between $n$ and $n+1$.

The point is to show that the property holds for $n=1$ and if it holds for $n$ then it holds for $n+1$, thus after inserting $n=1$ we get $n=2,3,4,...$.